# Prefs и debug address selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

мне нужно добавить в одну сессию webdriver две опции:

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {

                        "download.default_directory": captcha_directory,

                        "download.prompt_for_download": False,

                        "download.directory_upgrade": False,

                        "safebrowsing.enabled": True

                    })

options.debugger_address = f'127.0.0.1:{port}'
```

но когда я запускаю webdriver вылетает ошибка:

```
from invalid argument: unrecognized chrome option: prefs
```

на форумах видел похожие ошибки, но адекватных фиксов там нет, помогите пж!